# GitHub - LGTM and adding comments

Tags: github

I received PR and went to test, research etc.

It looks good but I would like to add details in `WRITE` box (where usually we just put LGTM) in terms of:

1) "I tested function X and Y like this..."
2) "Here is a link to online documentation for Y describing why it is a good idea..."
3) "LGTM"

So my keyword `LGTM` should trigger approval but would additional comments mess up finding LGTM (so in that case additional comments are not allowed)?

Also, is it a good practice to add more details (e.g. as above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my keyword LGTM should trigger approval but would additional comments mess up finding LGTM (so in that case additional comments are not allowed)?

No, as per the [official readme](https://github.com/lgtmco/lgtm):

> Project maintainers can indicate their approval by commenting on the pull request and **including** LGTM (looks good to me) in their approval text.

Emphasis mine - note that LGTM just needs to be *included*, it doesn't have to be the sole comment.

> Also, is it a good practice to add more details (e.g. as above)?

If more details would be helpful, then sure. But no reason to add them in just for the sake of it.

Comment: Regarding this.. If original developer did not include why he/she came up with that idea and implemented that way - is it a good idea to document that (2) above)? Or that is considered usually too excessive or not needed.. (thinking 6months down the road - maybe someone would want to know WHY it went that way)..

Comment: @Joe If you feel that the code needs to be clearer (whether that's through additional style, code comments, etc.), or more consistent with code that's already in the project, then I'd say the correct place to do that is in discussions with the PR author *before* accepting the PR. If you feel that it's not clear as-is and needs a comment to explain how it was done, then that's a good reason *not* to accept the PR as is.